# Windows: kill program that creates itself

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I've accidentally created a program that continues to call CreateProcess on itself - resulting in an infinite loop.

How would I go about killing this program once it's started to run? I have attempted killing this through the task manager, but because the program calls itself to start and immediately dies, it continues to disappear and reappear in the task manager making it 'unstoppable'.

The only way to stop this seems to be a reboot of the PC, which can be very inconvenient.

```
int WINAPI wWinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
{    
    using namespace std;    
    CreateProcess( L"self.exe",
                   NULL,            // No command line arguments
                   NULL,            // Process handle not inheritable
                   NULL,            // Thread handle not inheritable
                   NULL,            // Set handle inheritance to NULL
                   NULL,            // No creation flags
                   NULL,            // Use parent's environment block
                   NULL,            // Use parent's starting directory 
                   &lpStartupInfo,  // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                   &lpProcessInfo   // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
                   );

    return 0;
    //return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: reboot your PC and never run the executable again...?

Comment: Create a mutex to check if another instance of your app is already running. If it's running then simply exit before creating another process. Hint: use `CreateMutex` and `GetLastError`

Comment: @tobi303 I do believe I'm asking if there's another method. I don't quite understand the downvotes when I believe I've laid out my question clearly.

Comment: I didnt downvote, though what imho is not clear is whether you created the code really only accidentally and you are just looking for a way to kill the process (in which case my comment is a serious suggestion) or if the code actually does serve some purpose (in which case it probably needs to be fixed somehow)

Comment: @tobi303 Your suspicions are correct. The actual problem is that I have run into a program at work that seems to be creating another process which again seems to be creating the original (thus double looping into an infinite loop). However, I didn't want to clutter the question and hence have put up a more simpler, isolated version. I can see the problem and what to fix (in terms of the programs), but if this ever happens again (me or someone else in some related situation), I think it would be preferable to first be able to somehow kill the loop without PC (or even worse, server) restart.

Comment: The program you're looking for - while your machine is still responsive, is `taskkill /T /IM foo.exe` but then searching for 'windows kill process' leads you very quickly to that so I'm not adding an answer.

Comment: @dk123 You should have mentioned that info in your question. Maybe that's why people are down voting your question

Comment: Try to rename the executable file to prevent the running process from creating new childs. It may come as a surprise to you, but a running executable can actually be renamed. It may be locked while the system creates a new process so you may need a few tries (can easily be done using a loop in a batch file).

Comment: @zett42 I absolutely did not think of a looping batch file that renames. Please put up an answer and I'll upvote (+ mark as a solution if this seems most reliable)

Comment: I don't know how reliable this is. It was just an idea, I'll do some testing before I post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

From a end-users point of view, the easy solution is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and log off. If you want to keep the session alive the only solution to a fork-bomb like this is to use a tool that understands the process tree. `taskkill /T /IM self.exe` as suggested in the comments or the "Kill process tree" feature in Process Explorer. Child processes might still be able to sneak past so you might have to execute the kill command multiple times.

---

If I was programming a kill tool for this I would enumerate the processes and when a target process is found you open a handle to it and try to associate it with a [job object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161(v=vs.85).aspx). A job object allows you to deny the creation of child processes and allows easy termination of all processes in the job. Just call `TerminateProcess` if the process could not be added to a job.

You need to run this enumeration code in a loop until you have killed all the desired processes.